# Draw complex table layout in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tablelayout

I need to create a GUI in Python for a client server interaction. The GUI is on the client side for which I want to create complex tables. I tried to use wxPython's grid class, but its too tough to create a complex table in that. I saw a couple of examples for simple table layouts. 
 I tried to put up a snapshot of the complex table layout but the site doesn't allow me to. So, I am just drawing a format here :

```
[ Blah Blah      Heading ]
--------------------------
[col1] | [col 2] | [col 3]
--------------------------
   |   |    |    |   |   |
   |   |    |    |   |   |
   |   |    |    |   |   |
```

Can someone please help regarding how to draw the complex layout and which module to use?

Comment: Is there are design restriction that will prevent you from building a web interface?  Desktop network clients are the new Cobol.

Comment: Just the code should be fast enough. Like I read somewhere wxpython is faster than gtk Earlier, I intended to use gtk but then I switched.

Comment: There is no significant performance difference between WxPython and PyGtk.

Comment: whatever, I just need a working code. Do you have any idea as to how to lay a complex table layout in gtk?

Comment: I have used Tkinter earlier, do you know how to do it in Tk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter would be enough for this.

You can create any level of complexity on the layout even with the "grid" 
layout manager, which allows you to specify "columnspam" and "rowspam" for widgets that
will take more than a single cell.

Comment: thanks @jsbueno.. but could you paste some sample code of how to do that in tk? I am having hard time trying to figure out the layout.. if I can get a base framework , I can build on it..although I am trying to build it myself..but this is for a school project and I am running out of time..so please if anybody can help..